# Stored Procedure With Multiple Selects in Laravel Giving Only One Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I wrote a stored procedure of MySQL which should give 5 different results as output. That SP is working fine in PhpMyAdmin. But when I call this SP using following statement in laravel:

```
$response = DB::select('call spRebasedValues("1", "2", "100")');
```

Then it is giving only one result in output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$response = DB::statement('call spRebasedValues("1", "2", "100")');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DB::select('call spRebasedValues(?, ?, ?)', [1,2,100])
```